# How to change a css item in a template using django admin?

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to know if there is some way to change a css class from a template page using django admin.
I would like to put the django tag inside of css file.

example:

```
body {
    background-color: {{ body.color }};
    width: {{ body.width }};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also include your CSS file using template tags. That would demand a style tag but considering the dynamic approach here it's really not much of an issue:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        {% include 'templates/mytemplate.css' %}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The template could then be what you described above. Then the CSS template would have access to whatever data your base template has access too.

Depending on your use case you might also do something with blocks but I'm not sure that is worth exploring at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head:

- Create a Model to store the CSS values you want
- Register the Model to show up in the Admin Screens
- In your views, return these values as a dictionary
- In the template, use the values as you suggested

Comment: But I would like to put this django tag inside of css file.

Comment: @Hodson is correct. You could do this.
Then you would make your <link> tag point to the views URL instead of a normal CSS file.
You can call a template 'template.css' instead of 'template.html'.
You cannot just put Django tags in a CSS file obviously.